# CSS class not getting applied on Label of radio

Tags: css

This is my CSS snippet:-

```
.radio label {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

This is how the HTML is:-

```
<label for="contactmethod_delivery" class="radio tg-control-label">Delivery</label>
```

But the output label is still not as per the color defined in the CSS...

[image: Screenshot of the label]

I hope I am not missing any information required. Please let me know if I did. Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn about CSS selectors, and what the white space means between strings. See: [Selectors (W3.org)](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors).

Comment: you rather want `label.radio {`

Comment: This is not how you select `label` with a class of `radio`.. study css selectors and you will do it all by yourself

Comment: @DavidThomas for the link. I hope I could find the original (duplicate) thread by myself... I searched quite a bit... (but even the auto-suggestions didn't list the one)

Comment: @FotisPapadamis sure, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( "ancestor descendant" )`;

A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on, of the ancestor element.
So, your Code tries to find `label` child or grand-child of a element having `class="radio"`.

```
label.radio {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Don't separate your selector with comma, if both of your selector is within the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this only 
radio is the class of label

```
.radio {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how you select in CSS. Check [CSS-Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors).

In this snippet you select all `labels` with the class `radio`.

```css
label.radio {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<label for="contactmethod_delivery" class="radio tg-control-label">Delivery</label>
```